# Need help in solving for the roots of this biquadratic equation

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, roots, quadratics, problem-solving

I was trying to make random polynomials and solve for their roots when I came across this.
$$x^4 - \sqrt{2}$$
I tried solving for the roots by equating the above expression to zero and I got this:
$$x = 2^{1/8}$$
How do I find the other roots for this equation?
Are all roots equal in this case?

Please explain as elaborately as possible.

I am confused, please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the others differ by (multiplicative factors of) fourth roots of $1$.

Comment: Are you including complex roots in your answer? It makes a difference here.

Comment: I didn't get you guys.

Comment: $-2^{1/8}$ is clearly another root, right?  As is $\pm i\times 2^{1/8}$, if you are allowing complex roots.

Comment: Can you find the zeroes of $p(x)=x^2+1$ ?

Comment: $p(1) =2=p(-1) $

Comment: My bad, typo in a hurry. It is +i and -i

Comment: Your polynomial can be treated as a "difference of fourth-powers", so it can be factored as $$ x^4 - \sqrt2 \ \ = \ \ (x^2 + \sqrt[4]2)·(x^2 - \sqrt[4]2) \ \ = \ \ (x^2 + \sqrt[4]2)·(x + \sqrt[8]2)·(x - \sqrt[8]2) \ \ . $$  The first factor is zero for the two complex values and the last two factors are zero for the two real values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The roots are just $\sqrt[8]{2}\omega$, where $\omega$ is an fourth root of unity, because $(\sqrt[8]{2}\omega)^4=\sqrt{2}\omega^4=\sqrt{2}\cdot 1=\sqrt{2}$. Since there are four different fourth roots of unity: $\pm 1, \pm i$ we just got four solutions, only two in real numbers.